How to validate user input of either 8 digits whole number or a range into a textbox in ASP.NET webforms
I'm trying to validate a user input into a textbox in ASP.NET webforms.
The input should be either a whole number of 8 digits or a range from 00000000-99999999. So basically 8 digits on the left side of the hyphen without any spaces and the same way 8 digits on the right side of the hyphen without any spaces.
I tried a RegularExpressionValidator, but the only issue that I get into is, that the regex expression in the validator validates an input like 99999999-00000000 as well though this is an invalid range.
I'm not adamant on using regex so is there any other solution to this problem?
I tried this asp.net validation to make sure textbox has integer values
but it's not helping me either.

Please update to say WHY that question and the answers do not provide an answer you can use as in clarify "not helping me either" put code YOU tried in your question and perhaps we can update that to assist you here.

Perhaps you use 2 textboxes with a "-" between them? This would certainly facilitate such verification.

@Mark Schulthesis please allow me a few hours as I'm traveling and will update as soon as I get the time.

You can simple drop in a custom validation control, and then write out the validation in JavaScript.
So, say this markup:
    <h3>Enter a number range</h3>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"
        width="400px"
        ClientIDMode="Static">
    </asp:TextBox>

    <asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator1" 
        runat="server" 
        ErrorMessage="Allowed range is from 0 to 99999999" 
        ClientValidationFunction="checkrange" 
        ForeColor="Red" ControlToValidate="TextBox1"></asp:CustomValidator>

    <script>
        function checkrange(sender, args) {

            var tText = document.getElementById("TextBox1").value

            if (!tText.includes("-")) {
                sender.innerHTML = "Please seperate numbers by a hyphen (-)"
                args.IsValid = false
                return
            }

            var TwoParts = tText.split("-")

            if (TwoParts.length != 2) {
                sender.innerHTML = "Please enter ONLY two numbers seperated by a hyphen (-)"
                args.IsValid = false
                return
            }

            var Num1 = Number(TwoParts[0])
            var Num2 = Number(TwoParts[1])

            console.log("First num = " + Num1)
            console.log("2 num = " + Num2)

            if (Num1 > Num2) {
                sender.innerHTML = "First number must be greater then second number"
                args.IsValid = false
                return
            }

            if (!( (Num1 >= 0) && (Num1 <= 99999999) ) ) {
                sender.innerHTML = "Allowable range is 0-99999999"
                args.IsValid = false
                return
            }

            if (!( (Num2 >= 0) && (Num2 <= 99999999) ) ) {
                sender.innerHTML = "Allowable range is 0-99999999"
                args.IsValid = false
                return
            }

        }
    </script>

And hence this:





JavaScript variables by convention are typically started with a lower case letter for example var Num1 as var num1 Also consider the modern let num1 or const num1

I certainly have some code "smells" having come from other dev languages, and thus it occurs quite much automatically by habit.  . Always open to learning,  and difficult to change such habits since I'm working with about 5 different languages in a given day......but, am working on this!

LOL no worries, only suggestions on common practice like lower case functions vs upper case methods in c#, lower case properties vs upper case c#...main thing is all developers follow the same convention.  I totally get the multiple language thing as I work multiple and have worked dozens of different languages in the past.

As validation you might also add in number vs letter on the string split parts example 2e5 parses as a number but probably not desired things like that.
